Issue with creating MongoDB database using Azure Cosmos DB
Problem:
I am trying to create a MongoDB database using Azure Cosmos DB in Python, but I encountered some issues and was unsuccessful in the process.
Steps Taken:

Tried creating a new MongoDB database in Azure Cosmos DB using Python.
Followed the documentation for setting up MongoDB on Azure Cosmos DB.
Faced errors during the database creation process.
Tried troubleshooting the issue based on available resources.

Error Message:
2024-04-04 22:43:09 [INFO    ] cl_cosmos_mongo_db.py:__mongo_connect - CosmosMongoDB Server Connected.
2024-04-04 22:43:09 [CRITICAL] cl_cosmos_mongo_db.py:__mongo_connect - The user_data database does not exist.
2024-04-04 22:43:09 [INFO    ] cl_cosmos_mongo_db.py:__mongo_connect - Creating user_data database.
Arguments: (OperationFailure("Invalid custom action: CreateDatabaseCustomAction specified, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Invalid custom action: CreateDatabaseCustomAction specified', 'code': 59, 'codeName': 'CommandNotFound'}"),)

Expected Behavior:
I expected to successfully create a MongoDB database using Azure Cosmos DB in Python without any errors.
Additional Information:

Successfully connected to Cosmos MongoDB Server
My code:
          self.client = MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
          # Test the connection by accessing a database (e.g., admin)
          self.client.admin.command('ismaster')

          logger.info("CosmosMongoDB Server Connected.")

          # Access the database
          db = self.client[self.db_name]

          # Check if the database exists
          db_list = self.client.list_database_names()
          if self.db_name in db_list:
              logger.info(f"The {self.db_name} database exists.")
          else:
              logger.critical(f"The {self.db_name} database does not exist.")
              logger.info(f"Creating {self.db_name} database.")
              db.command({"customAction": "CreateDatabase"})
              print("Created db '{}' with shared throughput.\n".format(self.db_name))





full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Invalid custom action: CreateDatabaseCustomAction specified', 'code': 59, 'codeName': 'CommandNotFound'}

The above error occurs when you try to connect mongo service which was running on the same port in the machine. So, try to shut down that service while you are executing your code. Below is one of the approach to create database in Azure Cosmos Mongo DB API.
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_uri = "*****"
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
db = client['database01']

if db.list_collection_names():
    print("The 'database01' database is already exists.")
else:
    print("The 'database01' database does not exist.")

    db.create_collection('test_collection')

    print("Created 'database01' database.")

Output:

For more information, refer to this document.
